# Maple simplification incorrect?

Tags: induction, maple

I'm using Maple 16 to help me in some tedious computations.

I wanted to evaluate the following thing:

$\sum_{i=1}^k\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{l+i-1}\cdot\binom{l+i-2}{i-1}\cdot(k-i+2)\right)$

But if I enter the above into Maple, it gets simplified to:

$k+1-l-\frac{\binom{l+k-1}{k}}{2^{k+l}}$

I wanted to prove the equality via induction, but it came up that the two terms are (as far as I can see) something different (just try to set $k=1$).

So: Am I mistaken if I think that the input and output do *not* represent the same thing or is Maple mistaken for some reason?

Comment: WA gives a different answer: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5Ek%5Cleft%28%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright%29%5E%7Bl%2Bi-1%7D%5Ccdot%5Cbinom%7Bl%2Bi-2%7D%7Bi-1%7D%5Ccdot%28k-i%2B2%29%5Cright%29

Comment: @lhf, yes, I saw that -- while this *may* be the same (I did not know the Generalized Hypergeometric Function until today). But (secretly) I'm hoping that Maple is right, and the mistake is on my side.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a bug in Maple.